# Combining Pair with nested map

Tags: go

**Problem:**

- Want to read data from CSV file and group it based on this combination `warehouse[item[batch, qty]]`
- [Batch, Qty] pair should be inserted in sequence

**Approach:**

- I thought best way to make it is to use a combination of `map` and `pair/tuple`

**Code:**

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Pair struct {
    Key   string
    Value float64
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
    var inventory = map[string]map[string][]Pair{} //warehouse[item[batch, qty]]
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", inventory)
    inventory["DMM"] = map[string][]Pair{}  // map[string]map[string][]main.Pair
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", inventory["DMM"])
    inventory["DMM"]["Helmet"] = []Pair{}
    fmt.Printf("%T = %v\n", inventory["DMM"]["Helmet"])

    inventory["DMM"]["Helmet"] = append(inventory["DMM"]["Helmet"], Pair{"Jan", 10}) 
     fmt.Printf("%T = %v\n", inventory["DMM"]["Helmet"][0])
}
```

**Code error**

```
Hello, 世界
map[string]map[string][]main.Pair
map[string][]main.Pair
[]main.Pair = %!v(MISSING)
main.Pair = %!v(MISSING)
```

**Notes**

- It looks I was able to enter the `warehouse` and `item` combination correctly, but something not correct for entering/inserting/adding/appending the `Pair` to this combination!

Comment: You are printing two values, but passing one. fmt.Printf("%T = %v\n", inventory["DMM"]["Helmet"],inventory["DMM"]["Helmet"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the way you are building up your data structure, just the way you are using `Printf()`.  You have 2 format specs in the format string (`%T` and `%v`) but only pass one value.  You can recycle the parameter like this:

```
  fmt.Printf("%T = %[1]v\n", inventory["DMM"]["Helmet"])
```

Also you can just build your data structure with a single literal:

```
  inventory := map[string]map[string][]Pair{"DMM" : {"Helmet": {{Key: "Jan", Value: 10}}}}
```